# Unable to delete, update, or revert a file under Subversion ("Skipped paths")

Tags: svn

I have a file that I wish to delete. It is in Subversion, but I keep getting an error. I type:

```
svn rm importer.php
```

but I get the message:

```
Skipped 'importer.php'
At revision 20174.
Summary of conflicts:
  Skipped paths: 1
```

I can't do `svn up` or `svn commit` or `svn up -R #####;` they all return the same message. If I delete the file from the OS, I still get the same message.

Is there ANY way to remove this file? I would happily remove it permanently from the repository, if that's what it took.

Comment: One workaround is to check out again to a new directory and move your work to there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens when the working copy is too old compared to the client you are using. Either downgrade the client or checkout a new working copy with your new client.

http://old.nabble.com/question-on-summary-stats-after-svn-update-td25655840.html

Comment: Lovely. I think I'll check out a new working copy. Lord, there should be a better way :-(